# How can I pass a String as a model to a View in MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an action defined like this:

```
    public ActionResult TempOutput(string model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
```

And also, I have its view defined like this:

```
@model String

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "TempOutput";
}

<h2>TempOutput</h2>

<p>@Model</p>
```

Then, at one place, I have a return statement like this:

```
return RedirectToAction("TempOutput", "SEO", new { model = "Tester text" });
```

And the point is that when I get to my TempOutput view I get an error message saying "The view 'Tester text' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations.". But I jsut want to print the value of the string inside my view. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using RedirectToAction and not a normal return View(model)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are calling different override of `View` than you want:

```
View(string viewName);
```

You want to call [`View(string viewName, string masterName, object model)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492244%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) like following:

```
return View(null, null, model);
```

You can also specify explicit value (i.e. "TempOutput") for view name.

Alternatively you can force selecting `View(object model)` override by casting "model" to `object`:

```
return View((object)model);
```

Or, you can overload it using [Named Arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments)

```
return View(model: model)
```

Comment: Alexei, I think it would need to be `return View(null, null, model);` because there is an overload that accepts parameters `string viewName, string masterPageName, object model`

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly if you have to use the RedirectToAction you can pass model data like this:

```
TempData["model"] = "Tester text";
return RedirectToAction("TempOutput", "SEO");
```

More information about [TempData](http://www.devcurry.com/2012/05/what-is-aspnet-mvc-tempdata.html) found here.